# How to disable Steam on Windows startup?

Tags: windows-7, steam

I know I can use msconfig to do that. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open Steam, select settings, click the "INTERFACE" tab and uncheck "Run Steam when my computer starts"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [Autoruns from Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) and take out any Steam entry you see.